# Fire and cancel touch events manually

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, ios8

I have a question about programming my own third-party keyboard for iOS8. My keyboard already looks pretty good, but some functionalities are missing. If you look at the standard keyboard on an iPhone you can press any button and if you swipe your finger to another button, the touch event of the first button gets cancelled and your second button is "active". So e.g. if I press the button "E" and swipe my finger to "R" and release my finger, the letter "R" is the selected one. But I don't know how to implement this.

Now in my app when I press a button and swipe my finger around, this button never gets "released". Seems like I'm stuck on that button as long is I have my finger put on the display.

I think I need these touch events:

**TouchUpInside:** when the user taps a button, and releases it *inside* the buttons' frame, this event gets fired (that's when I want to write a letter)

**TouchDragInside:** That's the event when I already have my finger on the display and swipe my finger "inside" the buttons' frame.

**TouchDragOutside:** Same as above, just swiping outside the buttons' frame.

But here's the problem: **TouchDragInside** just get's fired for the button I tap. So when **TouchDragOutside** gets fired, I have to "release" the button and make the button active where my finger is at the moment.

I hope you understand my question, if you need some further information or some details just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider not using UIControl at all.

Just use a transparent overlay on top of all the keys so that you can manually deal with which key the message should be dispatched towards.

Comment: That's exactly what I made. But there was no answer to my question, so I thought it's not worth mentioning..